# Crash while downloading video via ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, crash-reports

Below is the stack trace by BUGSENSE:

Stacktrace:

```
0  libobjc.A.dylib 0x34a80464 0x34a7d000 13412
1  CoreFoundation 0x35818bbf -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] 22
2  App-iPad 0x0002839d 0x1000 160669
3  CoreFoundation 0x35818bbf -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] 22
4  Foundation 0x31181795 __NSThreadPerformPerform 268
5  CoreFoundation 0x358307dd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ 12
6  CoreFoundation 0x358025b7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 382
7  CoreFoundation 0x35801e5b __CFRunLoopRun 230
8  CoreFoundation 0x35801c87 CFRunLoopRunSpecific 230
9  CoreFoundation 0x35801b8f CFRunLoopRunInMode 58
10 GraphicsServices 0x320c84ab GSEventRunModal 114
11 GraphicsServices 0x320c8557 GSEventRun 62
12 UIKit 0x341dc329 -[UIApplication _run] 412
13 UIKit 0x341d9e93 UIApplicationMain 670
14 App-iPad 0x00003ac5 main 108
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: __NSThreadPerformPerform is generally used by selector methods, can you check at places where you are using selectors and not doing any wrong memory release?

Comment: Can you post code how do you make request and handle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that the `delegate` object that handles the `ASIHTTPRequest` has been deallocated.

Make sure you stop all pending requests when dealloc'ing your delegate.